# Why is my data not valid? (serializer.is_valid() return False)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Serializer

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Address1 = serializers.CharField(source='address1')
    Address2 = serializers.CharField(source='address2')
    City = serializers.CharField(source='city')
    State = serializers.CharField(source='state')
    Zip = serializers.CharField(source='zipcode')
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('Address1', 'Address2', 'City', 'State', 'Zip')
```

Model

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So in the shell(manage.py), when I run:

```
address = Address(address1='123 Sesame St', address2=None, city='Jurassic City', state='California', zipcode='90210')
address.save()
serializer = AddressSerializer(address)
content = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
stream = io.BytesIO(content)
data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
serializer = AddressSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

Why does serializer.is_valid() return false? It is possible that when data gets submitted Address2 could be null.

edit: The problem seems to be with address=None. Because when I put a string it will be valid.

Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 2):

if you run `serializer.errors` you will get `{'Address2': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')]}`

The problem lies in your serializer, since you are using a ModelSerializer I would just rewrite it like this:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode']
```

The fields must match the ones in your model

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error `{'Address2': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')]}` the serializer isn't aware that this field isn't required. So if you add `required=False` to the `serializer.field` the data is valid.

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Address1 = serializers.CharField(source='address1')
    Address2 = serializers.CharField(source='address2', required=False)
    City = serializers.CharField(source='city')
    State = serializers.CharField(source='state')
    Zip = serializers.CharField(source='zipcode')

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('Address1', 'Address2', 'City', 'State', 'Zip')
```